# Creating a valid new tag: eosio-cpp

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms, interesting-tags

Since `eosio-cpp` is the new compiler, and it is different from the old compiler `eosiocpp`, I think this tag should be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good idea, so I created the tag and tested it on this question:

[eosio-cpp get stucked when compiling “helloworld” contract](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/eosio-cpp-get-stucked-when-compiling-helloworld-contract)

̶w̶̶e̶̶ ̶̶s̶̶h̶̶o̶̶u̶̶l̶̶d̶̶ ̶̶a̶̶d̶̶a̶̶p̶̶t̶̶ ̶̶t̶̶h̶̶e̶̶ ̶̶t̶̶a̶̶g̶̶ ̶̶d̶̶e̶̶s̶̶c̶̶r̶̶i̶̶p̶̶t̶̶i̶̶o̶̶n̶̶ ̶̶a̶̶s̶̶ ̶̶w̶̶e̶̶l̶̶l̶̶.̶

Done.